# use UTL_TCP.connection in pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have to read a file .csv that is in a directory of my virtual box oracle. In my local system windows with sql developer i want to create a procedure that read that file in the virtual box. I don't undestand how use UTL_TCP.connection and how write that procedure

Comment: Rather than asking a new question, please update your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501621/procedure-pl-sql-to-connect-to-a-virtual-box-oracle-with-protocol-sftp-port-22)

Comment: `utl_tcp` is **not** for reading and writing files. you are looking for `utl_file`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using External tables.

Note that prior to creating external table You must have database directory created. The location specified is then used to read files from. You can specify separators, delimiters and filenames in the DDL statement withing creation of table. Once set-up it could be queries by using standard select statement.

For example:

```
create directory  << db directory >> as '/u01';

create table ext_filename_csv (
  column01 varchar2(4000),
  column02 varchar2(4000),
  column03 varchar2(4000)
)
organization external (  
  type oracle_loader
  default directory  << db directory >>
  access parameters ( 
    records delimited by newline
    fields terminated by ",")  
    location ( << db directory >>:'filename.txt')
);
```

Read more here:

http://psoug.org/reference/externaltab.html

Comment: So i have not to use something about ftp protocol?

Comment: I have not an external db on my virtual machine oracle.Thete i have only the file csv and i want to read it connecting with a protocol ftp as in filezilla.But i want to do that with a pl sql procedure om my local system windows with sql developer

Comment: If it's feasible transfer the file. Load it secondly. If not I'd suggest You to use any file sharing like SMB access host filesystem. Otherwise use package ftp package from plsql-utils. (e.g. [link](https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils/blob/master/ora/ftp_util_pkg.pkb))

Comment: can i use  utl_tcp.open_connection to connect with my virtual machine?how i can use that function?